# github3.py doesn't return file content for gist

Tags: github3.py

I use `github3.py` library in order to create and update Gist on github.com

I can access an existing gist and get all information except content of the file:

```
for g in gh.iter_gists():
    if g.id == content[0]:
        f = g.iter_files().next()
        print g.files #1
        print f.raw_url
        old_content = f.content #Returns None
```

Any hint why does it return `None` in the last line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though GitHub's API no longer returns the contents of the gist file as part of the response:

```
{u'size': 12, u'raw_url': u'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/testgh3/eb911d34ec732e4b7f24/raw/e041e7dc6236db21062c11b2929a72e656bbc40e/fileA.txt', u'type': u'text/plain', u'language': u'Text', u'filename': u'fileA.txt'}
```

This means that github3.py [needs to add functionality to the GistFile class](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py/issues/375) that you're trying to use here. (I've already created an issue for this. If you'd like to help do the work, I'm happy to help you with that and I'd love to merge a pull request with this functionality.)